# CodenameOne TextField (Area) emoji problems on iOS

Tags: codenameone

When putting i.e. a

```
TextField textField = new TextField("");
```

on a form it works perfect on Android but on iOS it gets garbled.
To reproduce:

- show the form -> textfield looks it correct
- focus it for edit on it by clicking
- change nothing, just select done / loose focus
- focus it again for edit on it by clicking

  **The result are strange symbols.**

`textField.getText().getBytes()` - on iOS gives the bytes: *-16,-97,-105,-67, ...* before the edit (the same sequence as on Android or in the simulator), but *-17,-105,-67,-17, ...* after ending "edit" (without editing).

It seems that a 4 byte code *-16,-97,-114,-74* for the  gets a 3 byte code *-17,-114,-74* after editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly suggest avoiding emoji's in the code itself. This is an issue with our implementation of the iOS UTF-8 parser that was resolved recently: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2365

However, it didn't make it into the 4.0 release so this should work within a couple of weeks when we resume the weekly updates.

Comment: The emojis in the code are for demonstration purpose. In the real world code it's about the user entering the emojis. Anyway, Labels are rendered fine, as are Textfields/areas set programmatically. Just when finishing editing it the text string gets garbled (maybe by the 'onEditComplete' call from the native code?)

Comment: As you will notice the issue I referred to was fixed just the other day. It should be in the upcoming update on Friday and would probably resolve this problem

Comment: Thanks, it works. But anyway, as so often, the update brought an other bug - I'm sitting since 12 hours trying to figure out why the app get stuck at some hidden point ... **Yes I understand you need to make money** with enterprise features and so on. But can't we other paying users just at least also **build one release version lower** by choice? Because my **entiere development is now halted** just because of this stupid new version bug, hopefully fixed in the next weeks (if we are able to pinpoint it in the next hours ...)

Comment: You can build to a point version e.g. 4.0 which we released last week with the pro account. You don't need the enterprise account for that. Then you would still have the emoji bug. The main problem with that feature is that people use it instead of reporting bugs. Then we can't discover/fix bugs. You need to explain the issue you are experiencing in better details so we can help and we do that for free...